# Verification of a Hadith Qudsi: "It is I who aids in proving and finding, there is no proof leading to me."

Tags: source-identification

In the book **Dialogue with an Atheist**, the author states that:

> God says in a Divine Utterance (Hadith Qudsi): "It is I who aids in
>   proving and finding, there is no proof leading to me."

I couldn't verify this hadith. Is it real?

Comment: Does the book give a reference to the Hadith?

Comment: To my knowledge, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hadith you are asking about is:

> أنا يستدل بي، أنا لا يستدل علي
>
> It is I who aids in proving and finding, there is no proof leading to me

This hadith is not in any known book of hadith and has no known chain of narration. It is mainly quoted from the book you mentioned, "A dialogue with my atheist friend", by [Mustafa Mahmoud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustafa_Mahmoud).